# React Material IconButton send object to handle function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm coding a list on ReactJS using https://v3.material-ui.com/ . In the list I place a delete button:

```
<IconButton
  color="warning"
  className={classes.button}
  onClick={this.handleDelete}
  value={item}
  aria-label={intl.formatMessage({
    id: "Worksheet.delete",
    defaultMessage: "Delete",
  })}
>
  <Delete />
</IconButton>
```

`value={item}` has the object I want to get to the `handleDelete` function. Now I'm trying to find out how to retrieve the object. I've tried `e.currentTarget`, `e.target`. It's not in there.

Am I doing it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: `onClick={() => this.handleDelete(item)}`.
This will send the whole object to the handle function